1950s comic book about bowling ball looking creatures that inhabit the underground of Earth
1950s comic book about bowling ball looking creatures that inhabit the underground of earth. When they play and fight they cause earthquakes.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did they interact with humans in any way?  Were there human characters in the comic?

@DavidW Noting Valorum's answer, do anthropomorphic ducks count as human?

@MarkMorganLloyd - Duck Tales is firmly on topic. They might, after all, solve a mystery or rewrite history.

Could this be Land Beneath the Ground!, an Uncle Scrooge comic from 1956?

In the caverns below Duckburg, Scrooge and his nephews soon discover that the smooth "rocks" are really subterranean beings calling themselves Terries and Fermies who look like bowling balls with arms and a head, but no legs, and move around by rolling on the ground. The Terries and Fermies can hear radio broadcasts through certain magnetic rocks, which allowed them to learn English - with a southern accent - from listening to country music radio stations.
Terries cause earthquakes by rolling in massive groups of thousands against the giant pillars that support the land on the surface of the Earth, while Fermies cause earthquakes by gathering together in massive numbers and lifting up pieces of the Earth's crust.



That was the story that instantly popped into my mind

@Lorendiac Same here, though I knew it from the Ducktales adaptation and had no idea it had existed as a comic as well (though I am not at all surprised by that fact).

I saw the question, and wondered if the DuckTales episode was adapted from the comic. Now I know ;)

@AustinHemmelgarn The relationship between Uncle Scrooge comics and the '87 Ducktales series is really quite tight. There's very few stories that were converted one-to-one, but there's a lot of story concepts and specific jargon that the cartoon borrowed.

@DarthPseudonym Yep, that I actually knew about for a long time, it just happens that this is one of the handful of stories that got adapted into the series from the comics that I had never seen as a comic. Stumbling across cool tidbits I never new about like this is part of why I love this site.

I never saw that comic and am only familiar with Duck Tails (2017) but I also immediately thought of the Terra Firmians.
